# How to add a background to terminal in Python

Tags: python, image, background, console-application, background-image

So, how do I add a background image to a console window through Python? I know how to add colours though.

What I want :
[image]

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Console windows are normally text, so how are you expecting an image to be drawn on one? What will the result look like? Is this Windows or macOS or Linux?

Comment: Edited please check